# Hats, or no hats?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

Stack Exchange last year did [an end of the year party](http://stackexchange.com/promos/12/winter-bash) featuring special hats. They want to know if we want to do the same thing this year to our site. So, do we want hats?

[image]

If our community decides to opt-in, they still provide an option for those opposed:

> Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see
>   hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option
>   available.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### **HATS**

UPVOTE THIS IF YOU WANT HATS

---

*Here's an [ASCII hat-wearing head](http://www.ascii-art.de/ascii/ghi/hat.txt) because apparently this needs to be 30+ characters*

```
        .----.
       /      \
       |=[-]==|
  (`.--.____.---.'\
   `-./<.><.>'\\_.'
      |  /.  .||
       \:-: .'
         `-'
```

Comment: Just opted in. We're getting hats!

Comment: wooo hats! I wish we could keep one for the remainder of the year, though. I loved the Watson hat.

Answer (score 4):

As a newbie I say, hurray for hats!

Answer (score 1):

It was an interesting diversion. I wouldn't be opposed to it, but I wouldn't feel cheated if they decided not to.

... apathetic enough for ya? :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for hats. Although I need to get an avatar first...

Comment: no you don't. I've had the gravatar-generated thing for like three years now, and I slapped the hats on it last year.