# Hats, or no hats? (2014 redux)

Tags: discussion, status-completed, winter-bash

Stack Exchange last year did an [end of the year party](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/) featuring special hats. They want to know if we want to do the same thing this year to our site. So, do we want hats?

[image: hats from last year]

If our community decides to opt-in, they still provide an option for those opposed:

> Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see
>   hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option
>   available.

---

<sup><sup>Disclaimer, I <s>plagiarized</s> re-purposed most of this post from [last year's discussion](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/8708)</sup></sup>

Comment: Yes please! Do eeet!!

Answer (score 9):

I think we should!  To me I feel it brought the community closer and we had a blast.  Lately I think there has been a decline in activity and voting compared to last year and it would appear some regular users have moved on.  We even had a few good questions come across from it but anything that can extend a fun experience on the site should be allowed.

Comment: Yeah I agree. I've been relegated to more of a lurker lately with work and school. That and the fact that images on this site don't pull up at work. Makes it kind of difficult to browse the site. SMH.

Answer (score 7):

Yaaaay, hats! My head is feeling cold already! And it might, indeed be a good stimulus for some additional activity. Can we suggest hats (some voting-inducing hats would be great!), or are we stuck with what SE makes?

Comment: There is a [hat-request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hat-request) tag at MSO, but it might be too late to get a request in for this year; the festivities begin on December 15

Comment: I guess I'll wait with my ideas till I've seen what we get this year. Thx, John!

Answer (score 5):

I say yes too! I liked the hats, and it would be a good way to boost activity.

Also I want to beat JohnB this year.

Comment: If you come at the king, you best not miss!

Comment: @JohnB I thought you lost last years king by one hat?

Comment: @Matt http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/graphicdesign.stackexchange.com

Comment: @JohnB well better late than never but congrats =P

Answer (score 2):

I vote for chapeaus this year. I mean, let's mix it up a little. :)