# Brace yourselves, hats are coming

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

I noticed on a few other SE sites that the traditional "[Hats, or no hats?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1326/hats-or-no-hats-2014-redux)" season has begun - but apparently this year, instead of sites opting in, it's assumed that everyone wants hats unless a site opts out. (mods - is this true?)

If you've got no idea what I'm talking about, it's [a fun thing called Winter Bash that Stack Exchange does every year](http://stackexchange.com/promos/15/winter-bash-2014) to <strike>maintain advertising revenue while fewer people are working during the holiday season</strike> make the sites more fun and keep people contributing while people have holiday season related distractions. If you do certain things in late December / early January, you "win" hat-themed stickers for your profile picture. It's like special seasonal badges, but more fun.

So I'm assuming we're up for that? Let's vote...

[image]

Traditionally, even when a site goes for it, individuals can choose to opt out (from a previous year's description):

> Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see
>   hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option
>   available.

Comment: Yes. Sites will be opted in unless the moderators come screaming and yelling at us to opt out. The only hold-out from last year (besides MathOverflow) [seems to be](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6406/winterbash-2015-participation) opting in this year.

Comment: Why are there two answers instead of a single answer that can either end up positive or negative?

Comment: I think more users can upvote than downvote, so it'd bias the voting? But mostly this is just how I've seen it done

Comment: Yeah but I'm pretty sure with this method now that your Answer for against got 3 downvotes new users can't even see it. Not that it matters, cause we love hats!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yey, hats!

[image]

http://designtaxi.com/news/359377/The-King-Of-Sweden-Likes-To-Wear-Silly-Hats/faq/

---

Or, I don't want hats personally, but I'll opt out as an individual, which means I'll stay hatless and I won't see anyone else's hats.

[image]

[http://imgur.com/gallery/MzVGwqg](https://imgur.com/gallery/MzVGwqg)

Answer (score -5):

Booo, no hats, let's opt out so no-one can have hats.

[image]

http://knowyourmeme.com/photos/731185-no-fun-allowed

Comment: This is actually fun answer... [:o)